# C - Optimization Boundary with Inline Assembly?

Tags: c, gcc

Consider following code:

```
// String literals
#define _def0Impl(a0) #a0
#define _def0(a0) _def0Impl(a0)
// Labels
#define _asm_label(tag) tag: asm volatile (_def0(tag) ":")
// Assume 32 bits
typedef unsigned int uptr; 

int main (int argc, void *argv[]) {
    register int ctr, var;
    uptr tbl[0x4];
    ctr = 0x0;
    var = 0x0;

    // Push some tasks to tbl ...

    // Suppose that tbl holds {&&tag0, &&tag1, &&tag2, &&tag1}
    // Suppose that ctr holds 0xC
    // tag* may exported to somewhere else.
    ctr = 0x3 * sizeof(uptr);
    tbl[0x0] = &&tag0;
    tbl[0x1] = &&tag1;
    tbl[0x2] = &&tag2;
    tbl[0x3] = &&tag1;

    // Run tasks table
    goto *(((uptr)&tbl[0x0]) + ctr);

    _asm_label(tag2);
    // Task I
    ctr -= sizeof(uptr);
    var += 0x1;
    goto *(((uptr)&tbl[0x0]) + ctr);

    _asm_label(tag1);
    // Task II
    ctr -= sizeof(uptr);
    var -= 0x1;
    goto *(((uptr)&tbl[0x0]) + ctr);

    _asm_label(tag0);
    // Continue executation
    return var;   
}
```

Can I re-write this implementation with inline assembly?

---

### Old statement

Consider following code:

```
#define _asm_label(tag) asm volatile(tag ":")
// PowerPC for example
#define _asm_jump(tag) asm volatile ("b " tag)
#define _asm_bar() asm volatile ("" ::: "cc", "memory")

int main(int argc, void *argv[]) {
    register int var;
    var = 0;

    _asm_jump("bar");
    _asm_bar(); // Boundary

    var += 1;

    _asm_label("bar");
    _asm_bar(); // Boundary

    var += 1;

    return var;
}
```

With -O0 gcc generates:

```
li 30,0
b bar
# 0 "" 2
addi 30,30,1
bar:
# 0 "" 2
addi 30,30,1
mr 9,30
mr 3,9 # r3 = 0x1
```

But with -O2:

```
b bar
# 0 "" 2
bar:
# 0 "" 2
lwz 0,12(1) # restore link register
li 3,2 # incorrect
```

The output is incorrect since the statements get optimized out.

Are there any ways to make a "barrier" of optimization in GCC?

---

Edit : Attempt #1

Adding volatile to `var`.

With -O2:

```
li 9,0
stw 9,8(1)
# 10 "attempt1.c" 1
b bar
# 0 "" 2
lwz 9,8(1)
addi 9,9,1
stw 9,8(1)
# 15 "attempt1.c" 1
bar:
# 0 "" 2
lwz 9,8(1)
lwz 0,28(1)
addi 9,9,1
stw 9,8(1)
```

In this case, `var` is put into stack (r1 + 0x8).

However, put volatile on `var` will stop all optimization about `var`.

I am thinking about make use of asm goto, but it is only available on gcc >= 4.5, iirc.

Comment: Try to make `var` volatile, too.

Answer (score 2):

> The output is incorrect

The output is completely fine, your code is not correct.

> Are there any ways to make a "barrier" of optimization in GCC?

The best you can get is

```c
__asm volatile ("" ::: "memory", <more-clobbers>)
```

However, that doesn't fix your wrong code.  The code is wrong because the inline asm has side effects you don't tell the compiler, this will almost certainly bite you sooner or later.  If jumping is what you want, then like so:

```c
int func (void)
{
    int var = 0;

    __asm volatile goto ("b %0" :::: labl);

    var += 1;

labl:;
    var += 1;

    return var;
}
```

Generated code:

```
func:
 # 5 "b.c" 1
    b .L3
 # 0 "" 2
    li 3,2
    blr
    .p2align 4,,15
.L3:
.L2:
    li 3,1
    blr
```

Comment: The reason I define symbol in asm block is becase I want to get address of label without using label as value, which is a non-standard extension.
Also, I am not sure if a C label ("labl") will be "precise" in more complicated case after optimization. I will check this later, many thanks.

Comment: @imakak : That is not label as value which would be `&&labl`.  The label is used as a symbol just like in C's `goto labl;`. You can even compile with `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` without problems.

Comment: Can I jump to variable (e.g., mtlr followed by blr) in asm goto?

Comment: @imakak : You mean like jumping to variable `var`? That makes on sense at all... I know nothing about PowerPC.  Can you restate your question in an architecture-independent way?

Comment: Okay, I will restate my problem later. Thanks.